# Different color for each specific character

Tags: android, colors, textview

I have problem on Android to do rainbow programmatic color on TextView.

Here specific condition of TextView:

- String on TextView may contain character and number in unspecific order.

  Example: AA11BB22, X2YY3ZZA1
- For character (A-Z), I wish to display color BLUE.

  For number (1-9), I wish to display color RED.

  Example: AA11BB22 will display 'AA', 'BB' will display BLUE, and '11', '22' will display RED in TextView.

I know, there few solution to do solve using generate Image or HTML on canvas.

Is better or worse to do generate TextView for each chunk of part then color it?

Or maybe your guys has elegant solution for my situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out `SpannableString`, [this may help](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of Spannable. This link will help you to understand how to use Spannable http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Spannable string. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html. The link provided by android.fryo is good and has a complete example.